# array of double variable showing NaN as output while calculating information gain

Tags: java

I've been trying to make a program in Java to calculate information gain for an attribute, given it's distinct values and all other required values.
Following is my program

```
package dwdmp5;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 *
 * @author Gaurav
 */
public class Dwdmp5 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        double P,N,IGtotal;
        System.out.println("How many total P values?");
        P = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("How many total N values?");
        N = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        IGtotal = ((-1)*(P/(P+N))*((Math.log(P/(P+N)))/Math.log(2))) + ((-1)*(N/(P+N))*((Math.log(N/(P+N)))/Math.log(2)));
        System.out.println("Overall Information gain = "+IGtotal);
        int numV;
        System.out.println("How many distinct values of an attribute?");
        numV = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        double [] p = new double[numV];
        double [] n = new double[numV];
        double [] ig = new double[numV];
        int i,temp=0;
        System.out.println("Enter pi for all attributes");
        for(i=0;i<numV;i++)
            p[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter ni for all attributes");
        for(i=0;i<numV;i++)
            n[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Attribute\tpi\tni\tI(pi,ni)");
        for(i=0;i<numV;i++)
        { temp = i;
         ig[i] = ((-1)*(p[i]/(p[i]+n[i]))*((Math.log(p[i]/(p[i]+n[i])))/Math.log(2))) + ((-1)*(n[i]/(p[i]+n[i]))*((Math.log(n[i]/(p[i]+n[i])))/Math.log(2)));    

         System.out.println("attrib"+(temp+1)+"\t\t"+p[i]+"\t\t"+n[i]+"\t\t"+ig[i]);
        }


    }

}
```

It's supposed to calculate the individual information gains and display them in tabular format. But this is the output i'm getting in case when I enter one of the values of `pi` or `ni` as `0`

```
run:
How many total P values?
9
How many total N values?
5
Overall Information gain = 0.9402859586706309
How many distinct values of an attribute?
3
Enter pi for all attributes
2
4
3
Enter ni for all attributes
3
0
2
Attribute   pi  ni  I(pi,ni)
attrib1     2.0     3.0     0.9709505944546686
attrib2     4.0     0.0     NaN
attrib3     3.0     2.0     0.9709505944546686
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)
```

The program doesn't show any error. The same values when calculated using a scientific calculator show correct answers. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: That calculation is a little complex so I didn't thoroughly check it (which would be your job anyways) but since you have the input values 4.0 and 0.0 I'd guess you do a division by 0 at some point, which will result in NaN (not a number).

Comment: use your debugger to find which subexpression results in a NaN. Any operation using NaN as an operand results then in NaN.

Comment: Your code is little messy, some spaces will be fine, but NaN can be eg. divide by zero or some cases like that

Comment: I suggest you follow the Java Naming Conventions local variables should always start with a lowercase letter. Also, you should always use curling brackets when using conditional or loop statements, because not doing so would make the code error-prone. And indeed, some extra whitespaces would make your code a little more readable.

Comment: Just tested your calculation and it seems that you get the following situation: `Math.log(n[i]/(p[i]+n[i]))` will effectively result in `-Infinity` because `0.0/4.0` will be `0` and thus `Math.log(0)` will be negative infinity. Now your calculation does `-Infinity * 0.0` which then results in `NaN`.

Comment: You end up with a Math.sqrt(0) in that iteration which produces NaN as a result. This will not throw an exception.

Comment: You got NaN when `i=1; n=0.0; p= 4.0` so you can debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html) (Java Language Specification) states:

> A floating-point operation that has no mathematically definite result produces NaN.
>
> All numeric operations with NaN as an operand produce NaN as a result.

Now when you read the JavaDoc on [`Math.log(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-)
you'll see this:

> If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is negative infinity.

If you have a look at your calculation you'll see that for p = 4 and n = 0 you'll end up with `0.0 * Math.log( 0.0/(4.0 + 0.0) )` => `0.0 * Math.log(0.0)` => `0.0 * -Infinity` => `NaN`.

From there the rest of your calculation will yield NaN due to the rules defined by the JLS.

Why is `0.0 * -Infinity` not equal to 0? Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/why-is-infinity-multiplied-by-zero-not-an-easy-zero-answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. Gotcha